# Convert Scala condition to Java predicate

Tags: java, scala

I am using the fabric8io Java library for working with Kubernetes in Scala. I would like to use waitUntilCondition function which received java.util.Predicate as the first argument. However, in Scala predicate is formed in a different form. And I get a compile error:

```
Type mismatch, expected: Predicate[Pod], actual: Nothing => Any
```

How can I define this predicate in Scala?
Here is the code I used:

```
client.pods()
    .inNamespace("default")
    .withName("app-driver")
    .waitUntilCondition(condition => condition.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Running"), 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scala 2.12 seems to compile fine out of the box on my machine, however in Scala 2.11 I had to use scala-java8-compat `asJavaPredicate` as suggested by @KrzysztofAtlasik (just type ascription did not work for me).

If upgrading to Scala 2.12 or importing scala-java8-compat are not an option, then try instantiating `Predicate[Pod]` and override `test` method like so

```
waitUntilCondition(
  new Predicate[Pod] { def test(pod: Pod): Boolean = pod.getStatus.getPhase.equals("Running") }, 
  15, 
  TimeUnit.MINUTES
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like compiler cannot infer types correctly. Maybe just try to add type explicitly?

```
waitUntilCondition(pod: Pod => pod.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Running"), 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```

You can also try to use [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat):

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._


waitUntilCondition(asJavaPredicate(pod => pod.getStatus().getPhase().equals("Running")), 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
```